# Hard drive undetectable after failed partitioning

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery

I have an internal 1 TB seagate HDD which I had about 800 gb of important data on. Recently I needed to install an OS on it so I connected it via external casing usb to my laptop and tried making a 100gb partition with Paragon Partition Manager and during the process someone canceled the operation. Now my HDD is not being detected on windows and also on a live cd i made with systemrescue cd. How do I copy the data? I have an external 1 TB as well which I can copy to. Please help!

EDIT: Okay, I tried booting from gparted live cd and it doesn't display my HDD. What now?

Comment: use TestDisk to attempt to recover the original partition. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk    http://thestarman.pcministry.com/testdisk.html

Answer (score 0):

try using gparted live cd to check, if the partitions still exist. If yes, try some kind of bootable linux on USB stick and rescue your data into other drive, and format the first. trying to correct it only can be dangerous. after copying the data, you can format the bad winchester and copy the data back, so it is enough to borrow someone's winchester for temporaily data storage